# Is it possible to add contact info to iTextSharp (5.5.xx) pdf signature field using MakeSignature.SignDeferred?

Tags: c#, itext

I have a external pdf signature provider, which is a web browser based service.

1. I need to send the pdf hash to it first
2. it returns the sign document (certificate)
3. Which I map it PDF using `MakeSignature.SignDeferred()` method

This all works smoothly, but with some limitations. eg.

1. I need to prefil all signature fields (correct me, if I am wrong)
2. `MakeSignature.SignDeferred` does not call the `ModifySigningDictionary()` (means I can't update the PdfDictionary after I get the actual signature info (name, location etc)

Please guide me with some sample code, as iTextSharp looks very complex to me :)

Answer (score 1):

`SignDeferred` is only for injecting a signature into a fully prepared signature field. I.e. it keeps all existing information in the PDF (like the regular content and the signature field value properties like *location* and *reason*) and only injects a new CMS signature container containing the actual signature.

It usually is used in a multi-step signing use case like this:

1. Prepare a signature field for signing in the PDF, in particular setting signature attributes like location and reason, generating a placeholder for the signature to be embedded later, and (optionally) generating a matching signature appearance.

   This often is done using `MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer` using an `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer` or a custom external signature container implementation also returning a dummy value from its 'Sign' method.
2. Calculate the hash value to sign from the prepared PDF.

   This often is done using the range stream retrieved from the `PdfSignatureAppearance` object after the `SignExternalContainer` call or already during that call in the `Sign` method of said custom external signature container implementation.
3. Generate a CMS signature container signing that hash.

   This is a custom step and details depend on the kind of signing service or API you use. In particular you may have to prepare a CMS signature container and only retrieve naked signature bytes for it from that service or API, or the service or API may already generate a full CMS container for you.
4. Inject the CMS signature container into your prepared PDF.

   This is done using `MakeSignature.SignDeferred`. And this step really only injects the signature container, it changes nothing else.

This use case should only be used if

- either the actual signing call in step 3 may take too much time, without a reasonable timeout, e.g. because some second authentication factor has to be awaited, for example some confirmation of some human user who currently is sleeping,
- or step 4 must be implemented in some different process, probably even on a different computer, than the initial steps.

Otherwise you should implement a custom external signature or external signature container class for calling your signing service or API and use it in a single `MakeSignature.SignDetached` or `MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer` call.

---

`SignDeferred` can similarly be used to replace the signature container in an already signed signature field in a PDF (if that signature is the outermost one), e.g. because the wrong signing certificate had been used in the original signature or because you want to add some unsigned attributes to the existing signature container, for example a signature time stamp.